# rendering pages on newly created subfolder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, hyperlink

Good day fellow coders, i kinda need some advice where did i go wrong.. it seems like after i created a new folder on the pages directory i can't seems to render the pages live or is it even possible or should i roll back and moved all my templates back to pages folder

```
**directory**
|_pages
    |_Accounting(new created folder)
       |_Journal.vue
       |_Cash Vouchers.vue
       |_CVPrint.vue
    |_Components
    |_Layouts
    |_Auth
|_dashboard.vue
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return Inertia::render('About');
})->name('about');
Route::get('/settings', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Settings');
})->name('settings');
Route::get('/journal', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Accounting.Journal');
})->name('journal');
Route::get('/cvprint', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Accounting.CVPrint');
})->name('cvprint');
Route::get('/cashvoucher', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Accounting.CashVoucher');
})->name('cashvoucher');
});
```

[image]

**Sidebar.vue**

```
<li>
            <NavlinkCustom :href="route('cashvoucher')" class="flex items-center py-2 px-4  hover:bg-gray-950 hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md"
                    :active="$page.component==='CashVoucher'"
                >
                <i class="ri-money-dollar-circle-line"></i>
                <span class="text-sm">Cash Voucher</span>
            </NavlinkCustom>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavlinkCustom :href="route('cvprint')" class="flex items-center py-2 px-4  hover:bg-gray-950 hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md"
                    :active="$page.component==='CVPrint'"
                >
                <i class="ri-currency-line"></i>
                <span class="text-sm">CV Printing</span>
            </NavlinkCustom>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavlinkCustom :href="route('journal')" class="flex items-center py-2 px-4  hover:bg-gray-950 hover:text-gray-100 rounded-md"
                    :active="$page.component==='Journal'"
                >
                <i class="ri-currency-line"></i>
                <span class="text-sm">Journal Entry</span>
            </NavlinkCustom>
        </li>
```

**Then my error is wrong because the due to it renders with dot(.) instead of (/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Inertia::render('Accounting/Journal')

Comment: this one temporary fix my problem but it gave me a different error but i guess i could accept this one for now since i have a general idea what would be the solution for that one error anyway thanks